# Batch-wise fetch records from cursor

Tags: sql, cursor, batch-processing, sql-server-2014

```
DECLARE table_cursor CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD READ_ONLY FOR 
     SELECT column5 
     FROM testdb.tableA

OPEN table_cursor;

FETCH NEXT FROM table_cursor INTO @m_column5

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    //two update queries are here
END

CLOSE table_cursor;
DEALLOCATE table_cursor;
```

Let's say this returns 10 million records. Can I fetch the results batch-wise in SQL Server 2014?

Is there a better approach I can go for? *(considering the performance fact)*

Comment: Most probaly two set-based update queries will run much faster.

Comment: If possible, loose the cursor altogether. It's impossible to tell the use of it from the code you shared.

Answer (score 0):

It is very hard to figure out what you are trying to do with that cursor.

Based on whatever little you've shared, it seems that what you really want to do is an UPDATE based on a [TOP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/top-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) clause:

```
UPDATE TOP (10) Sales.Store  
SET SalesPersonID = 276  
WHERE SalesPersonID = 275;
```

or an UPDATE FROM SELECT if you need a join:

```
UPDATE [dbo].[Events]
SET [datetime]=SYSDATETIME()
FROM (SELECT TOP 1000 [id] FROM [dbo].[Events] WHERE [datetime]<CONVERT(DATE,SYSDATETIME()) [e2] 
INNER JOIN [dbo].[Events] ON [Events].[id] = [e2].[id];
```

If you find that you really do need a cursor to support your process, you can probably then go with:

```
WHILE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM [dbo].[Events] WHERE [datetime]<CONVERT(DATE,SYSDATETIME())
BEGIN
   -- Your logic here
END;
```